# Android O : Ble Scanner not scanning - Not getting any scan call back event

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am using google pixel with Android O . I am seeing that in my application after a while there is no scan call back coming .

Below is the btif log I have captured

```
11-02 19:18:20.561 19922-19985/? E/bt_btif: bta_gattc_cache_load: can't open GATT cache file /data/misc/bluetooth/gatt_cache_4ae7ba3124fe for reading, error: No such file or directory
11-02 19:18:20.966 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_scanner: btif_gatts_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (26)
11-02 19:18:20.966 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_scanner: btif_gatts_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (26)
11-02 19:18:21.168 19922-19985/? W/bt_bta_gattc: bta_gattc_explore_srvc no more services found
11-02 19:18:21.190 19922-19985/? E/bt_btm: BTM_SetBleDataLength failed, peer does not support request
11-02 19:18:21.197 19922-19945/? E/bt_btif_gattc: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (7)!
11-02 19:18:21.197 19922-19945/? E/bt_btif_gattc: btif_gattc_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (7)!
11-02 19:18:21.198 19922-19945/? D/bt_bta_gattc: bta_gattc_get_gatt_db
11-02 19:18:21.235 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_scanner: btif_gatts_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (26)
11-02 19:18:21.236 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_scanner: btif_gatts_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (26)
11-02 19:18:23.804 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_scanner: btif_gatts_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (26)
11-02 19:18:23.805 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_scanner: btif_gatts_upstreams_evt: Unhandled event (26)
11-02 19:18:26.781 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=3 connected=0 conn_id=3 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=4 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=5 connected=0 conn_id=5 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=6 connected=0 conn_id=6 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=7 connected=0 conn_id=7 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=8 connected=0 conn_id=8 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=9 connected=0 conn_id=9 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=10 connected=0 conn_id=10 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.782 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=11 connected=0 conn_id=11 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.783 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=12 connected=0 conn_id=12 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.783 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=13 connected=0 conn_id=13 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.783 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=14 connected=0 conn_id=14 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.783 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=15 connected=0 conn_id=15 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.783 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=16 connected=0 conn_id=16 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.783 19922-19985/? W/bt_btif: bta_gattc_conn_cback() - cif=18 connected=0 conn_id=18 reason=0x0013
11-02 19:18:26.783 19922-19985/? I/bt_btm_sec: btm_sec_disconnected clearing pending flag handle:10 reason:19
11-02 19:18:41.281 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_config: btif_get_address_type: Device [device mac address] address type 0
11-02 19:18:41.282 19922-19945/? D/bt_btif_config: btif_get_device_type: Device [device mac address] type 2
11-02 19:18:41.760 19922-19985/? W/bt_smp: smp_br_connect_callback is called on unexpected transport 2
```

IS it a possible Android BLE bug

Comment: I just did the restart of the BLE(BLE Reset)

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I havent got any fixed solution for this .

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you don't call close() on all BluetoothGatt objects when you are done with them. Therefore you might run out of resources.

Comment: I do close after disconnection.At least from the API point of view.Though its return type is void so I cant be sure that the disconnection has actually happened successfully.Is there any particular log to vouch for which could be related to this behaviour.(no scan call back, or gatt close failure?)

Comment: @RobelRobelLingstuyl I didnt .